# PythonSelenium 3.x Implicit and Explicit waits not handling first 2 text field elements and partially works for the third text field element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried to implement explicit wait for the text field element, with several conditions but still not able to add characters to these field, it skips first name and last name field(most likely) and sometimes it skips some character. this is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.maximize_window()

driver.get("http://tutorialsninja.com/demo/")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@title='My Account']").click()
driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Register").click()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
#wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='firstname']")))
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='firstname']")))

#driver does not sends any characters to these fields and does not raise any error/excpetion that 
#means element is located and sending the characters to these fields but the same not reflecting in fields

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='firstname']").send_keys("first name")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='lastname']").send_keys("last name")

#driver send keys to these element, sometime partial characters to email id field

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='email']").send_keys("email@gmail.com")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='telephone']").send_keys("9898989898")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='password']").send_keys("password")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='confirm']").send_keys("password")
```

--->

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,10)
#wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='firstname']")))
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='firstname']")))

#driver does not sends any characters to these fields and does not raise any error/excpetion that 
#means element is located and sending the characters to these fields but the same not reflecting in fields

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='firstname']").send_keys("first name")
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='lastname']").send_keys("last name")

#driver send keys to these element, sometime partial characters to email id field

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='email']").send_keys("email@gmail.com")
```

using time.sleep(1) just before the first name text field it is working as expected, i just wanted to know how can i handle this with synchronization(implicit or explicit wait).

Comment: Add html code please.

Comment: Is input[name='firstname']  locator unique?

Comment: People are expecting you to accept an answer your problem it's solved

Answer (score 1):

You could just use webdriver wait for the rest.

```
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[name='firstname']"))).send_keys("first name")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[name='lastname']"))).send_keys("last name")
```

Comment: Then your locator is most probably wrong. Update your question.

Answer (score 0):

This should have worked.

```
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='firstname']")))
```

Condition `presence_of_all_elements_located` will not work because you have just one element
If `visibility_of_element_located` does not work, use `element_to_be_clickable` condition.